# Getting telegram group messages with Python

Tags: python, bots, telegram

I am trying to get group messages with Python I have this code

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, MessageHandler, Filters


BOT_TOKEN = 'YOUR_BOT_TOKEN'

GROUP_CHAT_ID = -123456789  # Replace with your group's chat_id

def is_group_message(update):
    return update.message.chat_id == GROUP_CHAT_ID

def message_handler(update, context):
    if is_group_message(update):
        message = update.message
        user_id = message.from_user.id
        text = message.text
        print(f"Received message in group {GROUP_CHAT_ID} from user {user_id}: {text}")

def main():
    updater = Updater(token=BOT_TOKEN, use_context=True)
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

    # Register a message handler with a custom filter function
    message_handler_obj = MessageHandler(Filters.text & Filters.update(message=is_group_message), message_handler)
    dispatcher.add_handler(message_handler_obj)

    # Start the bot
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But I got this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\FS\PycharmProjects\telegram-bot\bot-father.py", line 1, in <module>
    from telegram.ext import Updater, MessageHandler, Filters
ImportError: cannot import name 'Filters' from 'telegram.ext' (C:\Users\FS\PycharmProjects\telegram-bot\lib\site-packages\telegram\ext\__init__.py)
```

I am trying to get telegram group chat messages I created bot with botfather he gave me a token I used it on my code but have problem with libraries.

Answer (score 0):

As you may find in the [documentation](https://pythontelegramrobot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/telegram.ext.filters.html#telegram.ext.filters.Filters), you need to import `telegram.ext.filters.Filters`. Also, disable the "Privacy mode" & allow groups inside @BotFather bot settings.